# Hartl Rails Tutorial (3.2) 8.2.5 Rspec failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

UPDATE:

My test was not submitting the user info. The relavant code was in the previous chapter's exercises:

```
  describe "after saving user" do
    before { click_button submit }
    let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
    it { should have_link('Profile') }
  end
```

/UPDATE

I've completed section 8.2.5 (Signin upon signup) and the app behaves exactly as described:

- the user is signed-in upon signup
- then redirected to their profile page
- where the header has been changed to include a 'Sign out' link.

But my test for the 'Sign out' link fails. Here's my code, all copied from the tutorial:

relevant controller code (users_controller.rb):

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

relevant view code (_header.html.erb):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

relevant test code (user_pages_spec.rb):

```
describe "signup" do

  before { visit signup_path }

  let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

  describe "with invalid information" do
    it "should not create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  end

  describe "with valid information" do
    before do
      fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
      fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
      fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
      fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
    end

    it "should create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end

    describe "after saving user" do
      it { should have_link('Profile') }
    end
  end
end
```

The error is `rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:47 # User pages signup with valid information after saving user`

Thanks!

Comment: Aha - don't forget to make the test click submit:

Answer (score 1):

I think the last 'describe' block should look like this:

```
  describe "after saving user" do
    before { click_button submit }
    it { should have_content('Profile') }
  end
```

The test missed clicking the "submit" button before examining if there is appropriate content on a page.